# How would I make a flask timer that would run in the background for a user even when the user has left the page it keeps running? Without using DB

Tags: python-3.x, flask, timer

How would I make a flask timer that would run in the background for a user even when the user has left the page it keeps running?

Im making a site where the user claims something, then the timer before they can claim something again is 24 hours. How can I make it so the timer lasts and continues to work, after the user has left the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Store the time of claiming the object in the db and then when the user logs in again check the current time and minus the difference.

Comment: @LeonNunes Can  I do it without a database?

Comment: You'd have to use a cookie, but the user can clear those, a user session would be an alternative to that.

Comment: How would I do a user session? @LeonNunes

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/ try this extension

Comment: @LeonNunes I would be able to make a timer that would last even when the user leaves the page?

Comment: Well you would have to keep updating the session variable with the time and then subtract it when the session starts again which is risky since the session could get deleted due to various reasons, which is why a Database is more secure. Alternatively you could try this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp . It seems to be a persistent timer.